# Python - Plotly plotando imagem branca

Tags: python, plotly

O objetivo é plotar um dashboard, para isso, importei as seguintes bibliotecas

```
 # Importando bibliotecas

import ipywidgets as wd
import cufflinks as cf
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import chart_studio.plotly as plt
from plotly.offline import iplot
from ipywidgets import interact, interact_manual

import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default='notebook'

cf.go_offline()
```

E usei `return qf.iplot()` para plotar o gráfico desejado. Contudo, quando faço:

```
interface = wd.HBox([main_selector_box, secondary_selector_box])
outpt = wd.interactive_output(ta_dashboard, controls_dict)
display(interface, outpt)
```

Apenas uma imagem em branco é apresentada para mim. Já busquei ajuda em outros fóruns, reinstalei o anaconda e mesmo assim, o problema persiste. Grato!

Comment: Onde vc definiu main_selector_box, secondary_selector_box, ta_dashboard, controls_dict ?

Comment: Não coloquei o código inteiro pois ficaria muito extenso, mas defini essas variáveis em outros "chunks" de código e não tive erro algum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após trocar para jupyter lab, habilitei as extensões e finalmente consegui exibir o dashboard!